# How to get an estimate on an integral

Tags: calculus, analysis, improper-integrals

thanks for reading this, so i have this function
$$F\left(x\right)=\int_{1}^{x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t\left(1+t^{3}\right)}}dt$$

and it is asked to see the solution of $F(x)=a(x-1)$ for $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and I know the answer by studying the convexity of $F(x)$ and the coefficient of it's derivative.

However when I graph it in Desmos I see that in the original function $F(x)$ the value $F(0)=-1.89475996081$ and this is the part I don't understand, with the methods i know I'm unable to calculate the actual integral, or maybe I'm missing something.

I thought that for $F(0)$ the value would be undefined due to the discontinuity of the integrand function.

I would really appreciate any kind of insight on how to estimate or know that the integral is defined in 0.

Thanks so much to whomever reads this!

Comment: An asymptote does not necessarily mean the integral is undefined. For example, $\int_0^1 x^{-1/2} dx = 2$, even though $x^{-1/2}$ has an analogous asymptote on the vertical axis. In a similar vein, $\int_0^{\infty} \exp(-x) dx = 1$ is also finite, even though $\exp(-x)$ has an asymptote on the horizontal axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t(1+t^3)}}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$ for $t>0$, so $\int_{0+\varepsilon}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{t(1+t^3)}}\mathrm{d}t\leq\int_{0+\varepsilon}^1t^{-\frac 12}\mathrm{d}t=2\sqrt{t}|_{0+\varepsilon}^1=2-2\sqrt{\varepsilon}$.

So indeed the limit $\varepsilon\to0$ exists.